# Не срабатывает функция генератор, не пойму в чем причина

Tags: javascript

```
function* newFontGenerator(font) {
  while (true) {
    let changes = yield font;
    if (changes === "up") {
      changes = yield font += 2;
    }
    if (changes === "down") {
      changes = yield font -= 2;
    }
    changes = yield font;
  }
}
const fontGenerator = newFontGenerator(14);

generatUpFont.addEventListener("click", () => {
  text.style.fontSize = `${fontGenerator.next("up").value}px`;
});

downFont.addEventListener("click", () => {
  text.style.fontSize = `${fontGenerator.next("up").value}px`;
});
```

Comment: В консоле выдает "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')"

Comment: _Cannot read properties of null_ - это значит что у тебя нет `generatUpFont` либо `downFont` когда ты пытаешься добавить обработчик события

Comment: Спасибо нашла где ошибка

Answer (score 1):

В коде генератора есть проблема внутри цикла.

для строки

```
changes = yield font;
```

метод `next` позволяет передать значение, которое вернет `yield` и которое сохранится в `changes`, при этом в возвращаемом объекте поле `value` установится в значение `font`.

Из-за такой конструкции, отсутствует первая инициализация `changes` и пропускается первое нажатие кнопки.

Для решения нужно вынести инициализацию `changes` до цикла

```
let changes = yield;
```

в этом случае, при первом вызове `next` не важен текущий размер шрифта, и результат можно проигнорировать.

Однако следующие  вызовы `next` уже заполнят `changes` нужным значением и управление перейдет внутрь цикла

```js
function* newFontGenerator(font) {
  let changes = yield; // первый вызов `next` проигнорирует возвращаемое значение, второй заполнит `changes` и войдет в цикл
  while (true) {
    if (changes === "up") {
      font += 2;
    } else if (changes === "down") {
      font -= 2;
    }
    changes = yield font; // вернет обновленное значение и будет ожидать следующего вызова `next` для установки `changes`
  }
}
const fontGenerator = newFontGenerator(14);
fontGenerator.next(); // инициализирующий вызов, при следующем вызове `next` в `changes` будет передан параметр.

generatUpFont.addEventListener("click", () => {
  text.style.fontSize = `${fontGenerator.next("up").value}px`;
});

downFont.addEventListener("click", () => {
  text.style.fontSize = `${fontGenerator.next("down").value}px`;
});
```

```css
#text {
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<button id="generatUpFont">up</button>
<button id="downFont">down</button>
<div id="text">
  Text by text
</div>
```